# Show that $X(X'X)^{-1}X$ is identical to $XP(P'X'XP)^{-1}P'X'$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Show that $X(X'X)^{-1}X$ is identical to $XP(P'X'XP)^{-1}P'X'$

$P$ is a diagonal matrix with entries $1,c$, i.e.
$$P=
\begin{bmatrix} 
1&0 \\ 
0&c \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$X$ is a $n \times 2$ matrix with all the entries in the first column being $1$.

$X'$ and $P'$ indicate the transpose of the respective matrix.

I am having to use this in a proof that rescaling the data in OLS regression does not affect the residuals. This is the final bit of the proof but i can't figure it out.

Comment: Is $X$ meant to be an arbitrary matrix?

Comment: I'm confused. What is $P$ supposed to be? That specific $2 \times 2$ matrix? Because $X$ is usually taken to be something like a $n \times p$ matrix. What are the assumed dimensions of $X$?

Comment: Wow, i apologies, it is a kx2 matrix with entries of the first column being 1s.

Comment: $X$ is a $k \times 2$ matrix with the first column all being 1s?

Comment: If $P$ is an invertible mattix then this is trivial using the formula $(ABC )^{-1} =C^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki In the context of stats, $X$ is usually not taken to be a square matrix.

Comment: Yes but X'X is a square matrix so this will work right?

Comment: @Ello If you assume $X$ has full column rank and $c \neq 0$, I suppose.

Comment: (Take $A=P', B=X'X,C=P$)

Comment: @Clarinetist if that isn't the case, neither formula is defined.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki True. Anyway, I agree with your solution.